# How to copy a CGLayer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, quartz-2d

I want to save a CGLayer for the purpose of passing it to the undo manager. However, by the time the user want to undo, the layer will have already changed! So I need to create a copy of the CGLayer and store the address in a pointer. Something along the lines of:

```
 CGLayerRef self.myLayer;

 ...//stuff happens and self.myLayer gets its value

 CGlayerRef layerCopy = CGLayerCreateCopy(self.myLayer);
```

Of course, CGLayerCreateCopy does not exist, so what should I do?

Comment: Are you sure you want to copy the layer itself?  You're going to use a lot of memory pushing layers onto an undo stack compared to pushing the operations that the user performed on the layer.

Comment: You mean the CGPathRefs themselves? The thing I'm worried about is as the user makes more strokes, there will be more paths to draw into the final context, which will use a lot of energy over time.

Answer (score 1):

Can you tell us more about your design, why you think you need to store a layer in the undo stack? Conceptually, a layer inhabits the "view" position of "Model-View-Controller". The undo stack should really only contain model data and *apply* that to views if needed. So this sounds like something in your design should be re-thought.

E.g. if the layer contains an image, take the CGImage from its contents property and store that in the undo stack. Not the layer itself.

**Edit:**
Sorry, I mixed up CGLayer and CALayer. But the general approach remains: Don't keep around the layer. Create a CGImage from the layer's contents (or even better, create a CGImage to start with, then draw that into the layer), and keep that around for undo. If you're using some simpler drawings, use whatever those drawings are based on. E.g. CGPathRef, NSBezierPath or a custom object from your model that defines the properties these drawings are generated from.

Comment: Actually the only thing I am storing is the CGLayer itself. I don't think it has a contents property though.

Comment: Hello @uliwitness, how can we get CGImage from CGlayer

Comment: Draw the CGLayer into a CGBitmapContext. If you're on iOS there is a bunch of convenience functions for creating a context that you can draw to and get a CGImageRef from. But really, you should be creating the CGImage first, keep it around (for undo etc.) and draw it into the layer for display.

Comment: Err, the iOS thing gives a UIImage, not a CGImageRef, but both are images you can keep around, so who cares ;-)